# Iterative function

Tags: functions, iterators

I would like to write a bit of code that does the following.

Pick a random number from 1 to 20 (inclusive)

then if that number is < 15, stop

if that number is > 15 pick 2 numbers from 1-20, and check the highest number from the pair.

do the same check, if greater than 15, pick 3 numbers, then 4 then ectara.

```
f[n_] := Max[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, n]]
```

I made this function to give me the highest result from n rolls but I'm not sure how to iterate it .

thank you

Comment: When you pick 2 or more numbers from 1-20, are these numbers distinct or could be repeated?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci the numbers can be repeated

Comment: See my edit then.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a `test` function to control the iteration:

```
Clear[test, i]
i = 1;
test[i_] := Max[Sow[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, i]]] >= 15;
```

Use [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html)-[`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) combo to collect the results generated during the iteration, where [`SeedRandom`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) is used to make the random results appear determined for the purpose of demonstration:

```
SeedRandom[23];
Reap[While[test[i], i++]][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{20}, {16, 5}, {11, 1, 9}}
> ```

Comment: so it rolled a 20, then stopped, then it rolled a 16, then a 5, then stopped, then 11, 1, 9 then stopped?

Comment: @Wombles Step 1：it "randomly" gets a 20, because the max is not <15, so the "random" generation continues to Step 2; it get 16 and 5, again the max is not <15 so the iteration continues to Step 3; this time the max is less than 15 so the iteration stops.

Comment: Oh i see, thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach. This generates empty list most of the time since first number might be less than 15 more often.

```
SeedRandom@134
list = TakeList[RandomChoice[Range@20, 10000], Range@100];
TakeWhile[list, Max@# >= 15 &]
```

> {{19}, {4, 18}, {10, 11, 18}}

Let see next list

```
Take[list, 4]
```

> {{19}, {4, 18}, {10, 11, 18}, {3, 6, 5, 7}}

Here is the length distribution

```
SeedRandom@134
dist = Length /@ 
     Table[list = TakeList[RandomChoice[Range@20, 10000], Range@100];
      TakeWhile[list, Max@# >= 15 &], 10000] + 1 // Tally // Sort

  BarChart[dist[[All, 2]], 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{dist[[All, 1]], dist[[All, 2]]}, {Below, Above}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So What i ended up doing is this

```
f[n_] := Max[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, n]]
Tally[Sort[
  Table[First[
     Position[Map[f, Range[2, 100]], _?(# < 15 &)]], {10000}] /. 
   First[{}] -> {100}]]
```

because I wanted to figure out the probabilities of hitting any given stopping point.